# three.js get mouse coortinates on texture

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I want to create an interactive panorama like this one:

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html

but I want to let the user to interact with it.

Is possible to get coordinates from the texture on mouse move to create something like a 3d image map with three.js?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the story behind that 360 degree image you used?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Translating mouse location to Object coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023244/translating-mouse-location-to-object-coordinates/16389637#16389637)

When found triangle that ray intersects, you can gather that triangles vertices 3d coordinates and UVs. There you have enough data to calculate UV position for intersection point.

Pseudo-code:

```
x0 = mouse.x; y0 = mouse.y;
vec3 samplePoint = unproject(x0, y0);  // returns (x, y, near-plane-z) coords
ray.origin = camera.position;
ray.direction = samplePoint - camera.position;
var triangleComplexObj = check_for_intersections( scene, ray );  // returns triangle, it's vertices and their UV and 3d coord and intersection coord
calulateUV( triangleComplexObj , triangleComplexObj.intersectionPoint );
```

It's maybe a bit complex to understand but should do the trick. Hope this helps.

Comment: i've done something like this but the ray caster returns an array with no value.

this is my code:
var samplePoint = new THREE.Vector3(x0, y0, 0);   
var raycast = new THREE.Raycaster(o.camera.position, samplePoint.sub(o.camera.position));     
var c = raycast.intersectObject(o.mesh, false);
console.log(c);

Comment: I think The reason for raycaster.intersectObject returns an empty array is because the camera is inside the sphere